# How to route Gsuite email's through Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, smtp, google-workspace

So I have my amazon SES account, my Gsuite account, and my domain DNS settings.

I used Route 53 to generate my DNS stuff and used "use other name servers" and then entered my Amazon Route 53 name servers instead. I also added Gsuite MX records within my Route 53 and INBOUND WORKS...

However, I cannot for the life of me get outbound to work using my SES account. I tried generating an SMTP key on SES but cant find where to put it in Gsuite settings. I called Google and they said you need to put Googles SMTP settings into amazon but cant find that either... I just want to use Gsuite UI while having the emails sent out via my SES account.

On a smaller note, I'm having SPF verification issues too. I added "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com -all" on my Route 53 settings but it's saying "You are not allowed to use one of your sender email addresses" and throwing my emails into spam.

I'm not the most technical guy so a lot of it is learning as I go so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you all again!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are not clear on where things should be.

Your MX records are only receiving incoming emails, you can use any number of outbound servers as long as you verify those ones.

Send email via GSuite sould work fine, since GSuites verifies all your identify with the DNS entries.

**SES Process:**

1. Verify your domain -- Follow the instructions given by SES to verify your domain.
2. Verify your from Email Addresses
        This is essential, you are sending email, if someone replies you should be able receive the email back. In your GSuite, create an alias or new user to receive the email address you want to in From when you send your emails.
        Verify your email address from SES and you will receive an email to your inbox and confirm your email address. You can also enable DKIM setting along with this process.
3. Apply to AWS Support that you are going to send production emails.

Now send emails using SES API,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property

**Using SMTP from gmail:**

If you want to use SMTP from gmail, you can completely skip SES at all,

Use the following packages, enter your gmail credentials and send email.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmail-send

You can also search for other packages online to get the best that simplify your needs.

You also need to need to note, if you use gmail as your outbound email, there may be limits on how many emails you can send outbound.

Also with SES you cannot send spam or non-transactional emails without the consent of the user. Make sure you follow all those standards.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I already understand all the spam precautions and CANT SPAM act stuff so dont worry about any of that. So I have my domain and email address already verified within amazon but whenever I send an email out it's NOT through amazon SES (it's through google servers) !

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If you are stuck with any process in the flow, please share.

Comment: When I use a normal free gmail I can "add email address" under accounts and just put in the SMTP settings and generate SMTP username and password and that works fine... BUT on Gsuite it doesnt give that option anywhere!

Comment: Would sending mail through Node.js use my amazon SES account?

Comment: Got confused again, which is not working?  Outgoing Email in GSuite or Outgoing Email in SES?

Comment: Outgoing Email in Gsuite. I'm unsure how to use SES API and was wondering if I could just use my SES SMTP settings within Gsuite for quick authentication?

Comment: If you want to use gsuite don’t worry about ses. Use nodemailer and connect to gsuite to send emails. Also you cannot use any from email address. You need to have your gsuite registered for that domain.

Comment: I have to use SES because Gsuite limits emails and my email list is thousands long (food newsletter)! My Gsuite is already registered to my domain. I can already send and receive emails via Gsuite BUT I want the emails to be sent out through SES because I get 50,000 a day plus Gsuite IP's are more likely to get blacklisted.

Comment: If you are using SES, don't worry about GSuite. Register the email domain with ses, confirm email address and send email as referenced in the answer. Don't mix both.

Comment: I need to mix both because I am using a gmail addon. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I want to leave an update for anyone experiencing similar problems. Google Workspace (formerly Gsuite) doesn't currently have an option to authenticate with an external SMTP server or SMTP relay. Unless you can whitelist their IP addresses (i.e., don't authenticate), it seems currently impossible (as of July 2023) to have the Gmail inbox management experience, while actually sending emails through your SES SMTP server (if you're a Google Workspace user).

My solution has been to setup a subdomain to send automated/bulk mail from with SES (SMTP + MAIL_FROM settings with AWS on distribution.example.com).

Unfortunately, this means I still send/receive from individuals work accounts with the Google SMTP servers. So I can't fully manage the reputation of the individual work accounts, as they share the IP addresses with anyone else using Google’s SMTP servers who might be doing the wrong thing.

Comment: I've updated this with something hopefully more useful. My intention was to leave an update for anyone suffering from similar problems on the key words in this problem